# HTML table widths set proportionally

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed-layout table, with two columns. If I set the width of just one column, things are as expected ( at least how I expected them to be).

However, if I specify the widths of both the columns, cells start dividing themselves proportionally.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 5%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 2%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Ed</td>
      <td>Wood</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Albert</td>
      <td>Schweitzer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Fonda</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>William</td>
      <td>Shakespeare</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

What I intended was for the first column to take 5% of the row width ( 120 px ) and the second column to take 2% of the row width. However, the first one takes 5/7 of the row width and the second one takes 2/7 of the row width.

Is there some spec that details this behavior?

Comment: The widths of table cells of a table row will always sum to 100% of the row

Comment: could you please show me a screenshot of the desired output.

Comment: What's the use-case for this? Why do you want/need table-cells to account for only 7% of the width of the table? Why is the table so oversized in relation to its contents? As Itay has already advised the table-cells will always take up the full width of the table-row in which they're placed, which suggests that - whatever your use-case might be - you're using the wrong element(s) to accomplish it. But without knowing your goals it's impossible to provide any practicable help.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Itay, the total width has to match the width of the table. When you set the width of one column the only thing that happens is that first column takes 5% and the other ones take remaining 95%, if you add width to all, they split the space piece by piece until they reach 100%.

One way you could get what you're trying to achieve is have an empty column like this

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 5%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 2%;
}

td:last-child {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Ed</td>
    <td>Wood</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Albert</td>
    <td>Schweitzer</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Fonda</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>William</td>
    <td>Shakespeare</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That way, the empty column will be taking that remaining space and let your other columns have the width you specified. And if you do decide that you want the rows to span the full width of the table, `width: auto` will be 0 and shouldn't cause you any problems.

Comment: 'if you add width to all, they split the space piece by piece until they reach 100%' - this is what I am trying to understand better. Also, what you're suggesting can be achieved by just specifying a third empty column, without specifying its width at all. What I've understood till now is that if you specify widths for all columns, the row width is divided proportionally. Interestingly, if I replace '%' with 'px' for both widths, it doesn't make a difference. Its just proportions again. Say, the width for the first 'td' is 5px and for the second one is 2px, it's the same thing, isn' it?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true. It's a bad habit from running into way too many "why does this look so weird on this browser" and finding that every browser has its own default CSS styles has given me trust issues. And to be fair, I'm far from an expert as well, I can't seem to find any good explanations for what the process is exactly behind the scenes. I suppose it's just one of those things that work because they work.